# Android: ImageView, LinearLayout and TextView heights returned negative, 0 and 0, why?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to scale the image in my linear layout to fill the available space, but I don't understand the values I'm getting for the widths of the layout. Here's the relevant part of my main.xml layout file:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LeftButtonsLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/Jump"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/jump"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="5dip"
    />
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/JumpButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/jump"
    android:contentDescription="@string/jump"
    android:padding="5dip"
    />
<LinearLayout
```

Here's the onCreate() method of my activity, which has a debug print:

```
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LinearLayout leftButtonsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LeftButtonsLayout);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ResetButton);

    Log.d("DEBUG", CLASS_NAME + "scaleLeftButtonsLayoutContents: \n" + 
          "linear layout height: " + leftButtonsLayout.getHeight() + "\n" +
      "text height: " + ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Jump)).getHeight()  + "\n" +
          "image height: " + imageView.getLayoutParams().height); 

}
```

1) If I place the setContentVew() call after the Log.d() debug print, I get a Null Pointer Exception. Why? Is memory not allocated for the LinearLayout before it's used on the view?

2) The prints I see are:
linear layout height: 0
text height: 0
image height: -2
What am I doing wrong here? I expected to see sane values here, since I can see the imageView on the device screen.

3) I was planning to scale the image using:
imageView.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight. Is that right to do? Will doing this automatically update the imageView on the screen, or will I have to do a setContentView() again?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for your answers everyone. I've overridden the onWindowFocusChanged() method of my activity, but when I check the size of the nested ImageView below, it's reported as -2. Resizing it works, but I'm curious why it's -2 when it should've had a sane value. My code's as follows:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if (hasFocus)
        scaleLeftButtonsLayoutContents();
}


private void scaleLeftButtonsLayoutContents () {
    LinearLayout leftButtonsLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LeftButtonsLayout);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JumpButton);      
    Log.d("TAG", CLASS_NAME + "JumpButton.height " + imageView.getLayoutParams().height);
    imageView.getLayoutParams().height = verticalSpaceAvailable;
    imageView.getLayoutParams().width = verticalSpaceAvailable;

    leftButtonsLayout.requestLayout();
}
```

This produces the print:
    JumpButton.height -2

The resize produces a sane image, but why is the initial height -2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your points,

1) It is because you haven't initailaized your Button or ImageView. Since you call your Log before doing this, obviously the Button and ImageView are null and hence you get the exception.

2)And initializing doesn't mean that your view are completely drawn to provide you with width and height. So you have to provide the time to get itself drawn. But unfortuanately we don't know the exact time it takes to get drawn. So Android provides this method,

```
  @Override 
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) 
{ 
   // which gets called when your view is drawn. 
 }
```

Just now answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11078714/603744).

So what you have to do is, add your Log inside this method in your Activity and then check the resulting width and height.

3) To answer your third question, you definitely should not call setContentView() once again, which might throw you some other exception. But when considering scaling you might make use of some bitmaps to do this.

Comment: I'll try that out. To override onWindowFocusChanged(), I suppose I will have to create an inherited class from LinearLayout and override this method? Thanks.

Comment: no. you just have to copy and paste this method into ur activity and do ur stuff within this. It just gets called automatically when the view is done drawing.

Comment: Thanks for that hint, it seems to work. Last question, when this method is called, is it guaranteed that the children of the LinearLayout (the imageViews in this case) will also return non-zero values of getHeight() etc?

Comment: But when I printed out the imageView's initial height from this overridden method, I got a negative value. Please see the updated question, I've pasted a snippet of my code.

Comment: Since u r initializing imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JumpButton);     it there , the problem occurs. Create it somewhere in the onCreate itself.

Comment: I have a setContentView(R.layout.main) in my onCreate(), so I don't think the imageView is getting initialized here.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some answers for you:

1) If you place the setContentView after calling view.getHeight() you will get null pointer because that view is not set on the Activity content therefore you can't get a reference to it before setting it to the content of the Activity

2) You see that because the view doesn't had time to layout.. if you want to see the height/width of a view it's better to use a ViewTreeObserver listener like this:

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new     ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                /* don't forget to remove the listener after you use it once */
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

                Log.d("MY VIEW WIDTH","width:"+view.getWidth());

            }
        });
```

3) After you set the layout params of a view don't forget to call `view.requestLayout()` to make sure that your view will refresh. You don't have to call setContentView() again.

EDIT: Also the width of your LinearLayout has to be at least wrap_content if not fill_parent or a value greater than 0 if you want to see the child views of the Linear Layout..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do like this. Because the linearlayout is the main container of your activity. You cannot provide `android:layout_weight="10"` and `android:layout_width="0dip"` to the main layout. create one Linear layout outside this `android:id="@+id/LeftButtonsLayout"` and give the layout height and width to `fill_parent` or `match_parent`. This will work in your case.

And one more thing, You cannot allow to call elements of layout before the `setContentView`.

Comment: Actually the LinearLayout is not the main container of my activity, I've only pasted the relevant part of my main.xml layout file here. There are other containers present which take up the remaining weights.